# How to combine a few lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, numerics

There are two lists: `a={12,23,4,5,7}`, `b={11,3,24,5}`

I would like to combine them like this: `ab={12,11,23,3,4,24,5,5,7}`

How it can be done?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a={12,23,4,5,7};
b={11,3,24,5};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way out of many could be

```
Riffle[a, b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]