# How to Riffle lists without cyclic repetitions

Tags: list-manipulation

To the follow to my previous question [How to combine a few lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284700/how-to-combine-a-few-lists).

There are two lists: `a={1,2,4,5,7,6,9,2}`, `b={1,3,4}`
I would like to get the next lists:

1. `ab1={1,1,2,3,4,4,5,7,6,9,2}` (the first element of `b` is placed between the first and second elements of `a`, the second element of `b` is placed between the second and third elements of `a`, etc)
2. `ab2={1,2,4,5,7,1,6,3,9,4,2}` (similar to 1., but put the elements of the list `b` from the end of the list `a`)
3. `ab3={1,2,1,4,3,5,4,7,6,9,2}` (in this case elements of `b` can be placed in a specific place of the list `a`, in particular here the first element of `b` is placed between the second and third elements of the list `a`, etc )

Comment: As `Flatten` may be used to [Transpose a 'ragged' array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106), `(Flatten[{a,b},{{2}}]//Flatten)==ab1`

Answer (score 5):

**Using `PadRight`:**

First, the explanation:

```
PadRight[{a, b}, {2, Max[{Length@a, Length@b}]}, \[Wolf]] // Grid
```

[image]

Keep reading from top to bottom and across. At the end, delete the symbol that was introduced. This prevents the cyclic riffle effect.

```
(PadRight[{a, b}, {2, Max[{Length@a, Length@b}]}, \[Wolf]] // 
    Transpose // Flatten) /. \[Wolf] -> Nothing
```

> {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 2}

---

Second case is just the reversal of the idea. Don't forget to reverse the generated list at the end.

```
(PadRight[{Reverse@a, Reverse@b}, {2, 
       Max[{Length@a, Length@b}]}, \[Wolf]] // Transpose // 
    Flatten) /. \[Wolf] -> Nothing // Reverse
```

> {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2}

---

For the third case, `PadRight` provides an additional parameter that can be used to pad elements at the left. Do so with the second list only so as to shift it right by one.

```
({PadRight[a, Max[{Length@a, Length@b}], \[Wolf]]
     , PadRight[b, Max[{Length@a, Length@b}], \[Wolf], 1]
     } // Transpose // Flatten) /. \[Wolf] -> Nothing
```

> {1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 2}

---

Now I have to invest time in learning about `Riffle` for which two excellent answers already exist.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting explanation!

Answer (score 4):

You may use "Riffle" like:

1. First element of b  at place 2:

   a = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9, 2};
   b = {1, 3, 4};

   Riffle[a, b, {2, 2 Length[b], 2}]
2. Last element of b at second to last place:

   Riffle[a, b, {Length[a] - Length[b] + 1, Length[a] + Length[b], 2}]

   {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2}
3. 3. First element of b at position 3;

   Riffle[a, b, {3, (Length[a] + Length[b]) - 3, 2}]

   {1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 2}

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
riffle[a_, b_, start_, step_] := Riffle[a, b, 
  Append[step] @
  If[Positive @ start, Identity, Reverse] @
  (start + {0, Sign[start] step (Length @ b - 1)})]
```

***Examples:***

```
a = {1,2,4,5,7,6,9,2};
b = {1,3,4};

riffle[a, b, 2, 2] == ab1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
riffle[a, b, -2, 2] == ab2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
riffle[a, b, 3, 2] == ab3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
bb = {b1, b2, b3};

riffle[a, bb, 2, 2]
```

> ```
> {1, b1, 2, b2, 4, b3, 5, 7, 6, 9, 2}
> ```

```
riffle[a, bb, 3, 2]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, b1, 4, b2, 5, b3, 7, 6, 9, 2}
> ```

```
riffle[a, bb, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, b1, 2, 4, b2, 5, 7, b3, 6, 9, 2}
> ```

```
riffle[a, bb, -2, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 4, b1, 5, 7, b2, 6, 9, b3, 2}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much!