# How to join two tables in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, table, join

Consider two tables

```
tab1={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

tab2={{7,8},{9,10},{11,12}};
```

How to join these tables in a way such that the ith column of `tab2` would be just below the ith row of `tab1`:

```
tab3 = {{1,2},{7,8},{3,4},{9,10},{5,6},{11,12}}
```

?

Comment: `Riffle[tab1, tab2]`?

Comment: see similar one  [how-to-combine-a-few-lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284700/how-to-combine-a-few-lists/)